# Test if user passed in a shell variable

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell function that I would like to check if the user passed in a second variable. I have tried this but it does not seem to be working

```
function dash() {
    if [ -z "$2" ]; then
        open dash://$1:$2;
    else
        open dash://$1;
    fi
}
```

Basically, I want to say if a second argument `$2` is passed in do 'X' else do 'Y'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
function dash() {
  open dash://$1${2+:}$2
}
```

The `${2+:}` expands to a `:` if `$2` is set, and the null string otherwise.

Comment: heh. as my kid would say, "jinx!".

Answer (score 2):

`$#` gives the number of arguments passed

```
if [ $# -eq 2 ]
then
  echo "2 arguments passed"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have it backwards - the "-z" tests for a null string.  So, just swap it or use "-n" (not null):

```
function dash() {
    if [ -n "$2" ]; then
        open dash://$1:$2;
    else
        open dash://$1;
    fi
}
```

This site is a good one for more information:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Answer (score 0):

The function could be fixed by this

```
function dash() {
    if [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
        open "dash://$1:$2"
    else
        open "dash://$1"
    fi
}
```

- You can use `$#` to check the number of arguments.
- Quote your argument to preserve possible spaces.

And when calling your function, quote it as well:

```
dash "first argument" "second argument"
```

Or

```
dash "first argument"
```

If you do this:

```
first='first argument'
dash $first
```

There would be two arguments (first and argument), instead of just one.